# Navigation custom titleView no longer visible only on iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11, custom-view, searchbar, titleview

I have a custom view as search bar and set it to Navigation titleView. CustomView is no longer visible on iOS 11 devices alone. I debugged with Hierarchy View and I found that custom view's frame size is (0,0).

This issue happens only on iOS 11, it works fine on iOS 9 and 10.

```
UIView *searchBarView = [self createSearchBarView];  // Custom searchBarView
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView;
searchBarView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

How can I add custom view as Navigation's titleView on iOS 11?

Answer (score 4):

In your custom `UIView` overrire below method

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
   return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize
}
```

Check and let me know is it working for your or not ?